# Cordova Kiosk mode for android

Tags: android, cordova, kiosk-mode

I want to code a cordova app in kiosk mode.
I have found [this Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627674/kiosk-mode-for-android).

But if I add the code I am getting a Error on create the apk.

```
C:\temp\ksl\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\temp\ksl\platforms\
adlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\temp\ksl\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dor
aemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\temp\ksl\platforms\andr
a\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\temp\ksl\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed
 code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\ebay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Without your code if got no error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now included in Android 5.0 Lollipop core. It's called pinning and you can access it via parameters->security->pinning.
Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the Kiosk mode. It still exposes lots of information.