# Android Run App in kiosk mode to selected user

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, kiosk-mode

I have tablet with android 4.4.4 which has 2 users, one of them must run only one app (that app is not write by me). In Linux all i need to do is setup shell on /etc/passwd. How to easiest way to do it with Android. Just all that user can do is run selected app, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable USB Debugging on Your Phone. To use ADB with your **Android device**, you must enable a feature called **USB debugging**. Open your phone's app drawer, tap the Settings icon, and select “About Phone”.

Scroll all the way down and tap the “Build Number” item seven times
Debug mode is open and you can run ADB shell commands when you connect your PC [Follow this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html)

To test whether ADB is working properly, connect your Android device to your computer using a USB cable and run the following command:

**adb devices**

1. [Kiosk Mode for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627674/kiosk-mode-for-android?rq=1)
2. [Kiosk Mode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: I connected that android to computer, but i ask about making kiosk app

Comment: android VNC client, i found source of this if it helps @ashes

Comment: @wytrzeszcz i have two other links from SO chk it ,it will also help you ! grt day